# Twitter: Unread direct messages using the Twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

Twitter:

I must be blind, but how would I find out how many unread direct messages a certain user has?

I'm using this documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Twitter doesn't offer this functionality.  There is no way, currently, for Twitter to store which direct messages(or mentions or statuses for that matter) a user has read or hasn't read.

Though I believe they are looking into it.

Comment: I haven't done any Twitter API coding for years, but hopefully they are still looking into it.

Answer (score 6):

*Unread* is a vaguely defined term. *Unread* is usually used in a specific client application. So, for instance, if you are using Twitterrific in two different machines with the same user account, both client instances will have different *unread messages* with respect to each other.

If you want to keep track of *unread* messages for **your** client, you must store the last message read **ID**. Each Twitter status is uniquely identified by a **long number** representing a global message **ID**, so it should not be difficult to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, I'm not working on a Twitter client in that sense.
I guess in my case, I don't care if the user has used the Twitter website or any other client to read a message, I just want to know if a message is unread or not. Actually I'd be happy to find out something like "You have 2 unread messages at Twitter". Then I'll just provide a link to the Twitter website.

Comment: No. You can't do that with twitter API. One thing you can do is, on your website, store the LAST MESSAGE ID you informed the user about, and act accordingly.

Comment: Well yes, but that would only mean that I can have my system remember the latest message id that was seen by my system. If the system discovers a new latest message id, the user might have already read the message in question with another Twitter client. As the answer below states, I guess what I'm asking isn't possible at this moment.

Comment: As mentioned, it is not possible now.

Comment: The official twitter client propagates, which DMs are read and removes the notification on other devices. The API seems not to have such an feature.